# How to run vcxproj in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++

I want to run the code in this project in Ubuntu: https://github.com/yusufasln26/geneticAlgorithm-pathPlanning It is GUI C++ project. I tried to run this project using Ubuntu Terminal, but it did not show the grid in Readme.md description in the above link.

Generally, I need to run many previously created c++ projects in Ubuntu. What is the best IDE to run c++ projects in Ubuntu.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Since this is a c++ project, you need to compile the code, and not run it. It's unclear what you've done to "run" it, and what was the result.

Answer (score 1):

***vcxproj*** files are specific for Microsoft Visual Studio, the project file in that github repository used MS Visual Studio 2015.  One IDE available for Ubuntu is Code::Blocks.  Visit http://www.codeblocks.org

As far as i know there is no tool to convert ***vcxproj*** to ***Makefile***.